# How to remove the last line/component/icon/widget/etc. from JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I have a massive Java project which utilizes a console like UI. For the console, I use a JTextPane. Recently I have need for methods to remove the first and last line respectively. The method I have for removing the first line is quite trivial and is as follows

```java
public void removeFirstLine() {
        try {
            Element root = outputArea.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
            Element first = root.getElement(0);
            outputArea.getDocument().remove(first.getStartOffset(), first.getEndOffset());
            outputArea.setCaretPosition(outputArea.getDocument().getLength());
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            ErrorHandler.handle(e);
        }
    }
```

My problem, however, comes when I try to remove the very last line (NOT OF TEXT I REPEAT NOT OF TEXT). This line could be anything appendable to a JTextPane such as a custom component, a string of text, an icon, etc. If anyone knows how to remove the last "thing" appended to a JTextPane, I would be ever-grateful to you.

EDIT: add minimal Reproducible example:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    private static final String ELEM = AbstractDocument.ElementNameAttribute;
    private static final String ICON = StyleConstants.IconElementName;
    private static final String COMP = StyleConstants.ComponentElementName;
    private JTextPane outputArea;

    Test() {
        try {
            //init pane
            outputArea = new JTextPane();

            //insert component
            JTextField c = new JTextField(20);
            Style cs = outputArea.getStyledDocument().addStyle("name", null);
            StyleConstants.setComponent(cs, c);
            outputArea.getStyledDocument().insertString(outputArea.getStyledDocument().getLength(), "string", cs);

            //new line
            println("");

            //add string
            println("this is a string added to the pane");

            //add image
            outputArea.insertIcon(new ImageIcon("/path/to/image.png"));

            //new line
            println("");

            //before
            printContents();

            //----------------------------
            //call removeLastLine() as many times as needed and it should remove the last added "thing"
            //regardless of the order added (ex: component, text, icon should function the same as text, text, text, component obviously)

            //changes should be reflected here
            printContents();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void removeLastLine() {
        //TODO remove last line of text, last component, last image icon, etc.
    }

    public void println(String Usage) {
        try {
            StyledDocument document = (StyledDocument) outputArea.getDocument();
            document.insertString(document.getLength(), Usage + "\n", null);
            outputArea.setCaretPosition(outputArea.getDocument().getLength());
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void printContents() {
        try {
            ElementIterator iterator = new ElementIterator(outputArea.getStyledDocument());
            Element element;
            while ((element = iterator.next()) != null) {
                System.out.println(element);
                AttributeSet as = element.getAttributes();
                if (as.containsAttribute(ELEM, ICON)) {
                    System.out.println(StyleConstants.getIcon(as).getClass());
                }
                else if (as.containsAttribute(ELEM, COMP)) {
                    System.out.println(StyleConstants.getComponent(as).getClass());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: got an image so we know what you mean?

Comment: @NathanVincent A better MRE would be a JFrame with your text pane and data as was already suggest by Abra. Then you add a "Remove Last Line" button. Each time you click the button you remove a line. This will allow you to visually see if the text pane changes rather than trying to compare output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue with the following code which I spent the whole afternoon writing.

```java
 /**
     * Removes the last "thing" addeed to the JTextPane whether it's a component,
     *  icon, or string of multi-llined text.
     *
     *  In more detail, this method figures out what it'll be removing and then determines how many calls
     *   are needed to {@link StringUtil#removeLastLine()}
     */
 public void removeLast() {
        boolean removeTwoLines = false;

        LinkedList<Element> elements = new LinkedList<>();
        ElementIterator iterator = new ElementIterator(outputArea.getStyledDocument());
        Element element;
        while ((element = iterator.next()) != null) {
            elements.add(element);
        }

        int leafs = 0;

        for (Element value : elements)
            if (value.getElementCount() == 0)
                leafs++;

        int passedLeafs = 0;

        for (Element value : elements) {
            if (value.getElementCount() == 0) {
                if (passedLeafs + 3 != leafs) {
                    passedLeafs++;
                    continue;
                }

                if (value.toString().toLowerCase().contains("icon") || value.toString().toLowerCase().contains("component")) {
                    removeTwoLines = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (removeTwoLines) {
            removeLastLine();
        }

        removeLastLine();
    }

    /**
     * Removes the last line added to the linked JTextPane. This could appear to remove nothing,
     *  but really be removing just a newline (line break) character.
     */
    public void removeLastLine() {
        try {
            LinkedList<Element> elements = new LinkedList<>();
            ElementIterator iterator = new ElementIterator(outputArea.getStyledDocument());
            Element element;
            while ((element = iterator.next()) != null) {
                elements.add(element);
            }

            int leafs = 0;

            for (Element value : elements)
                if (value.getElementCount() == 0)
                    leafs++;

            int passedLeafs = 0;

            for (Element value : elements) {
                if (value.getElementCount() == 0) {
                    if (passedLeafs + 2 != leafs) {
                        passedLeafs++;
                        continue;
                    }

                    outputArea.getStyledDocument().remove(value.getStartOffset(),
                            value.getEndOffset() - value.getStartOffset());
                }
            }
        } catch (BadLocationException ignored) {}
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The full code can be viewed at the following: https://github.com/NathanCheshire/Cyder/blob/master/src/cyder/utilities/StringUtil.java

Comment: Seems overly complex when all you needed was a simple if condition added to my original suggestion, to properly handle removal of the first line.

Comment: As stated previously, your original suggestion did not work, please see my github at NathanCheshire/cyder if you would like to clone my project and test our your "solution". You seem quite eager for me accept your answer when it in fact did not solve my issue which,.

Comment: *your original suggestion did not work* - I agreed it had an issue removing the "first line" from the text pane whether that first line was text or a JTextField. This is why you do debugging to determine the problem (instead of assuming the problem was with the JTextField) and then work to fix the problem. I updated my answer to provide a solution based on your posted (pseudo) MRE. If your MRE doesn't demonstrate the actual problem, then that is your issue not ours. We can't guess what the real problem is if you can't replicate it in an MRE.

Answer (score 0):

Following is code I have used before, for removing text:

```
public void removeLastLine() {
    //  We use start minus 1 to make sure we remove the newline
    //  character of the previous line
    Element root = outputArea.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
    Element line = root.getElement(root.getElementCount() - 1);
    int start = line.getStartOffset();
    int end = line.getEndOffset();

    try
    {
        outputArea.getDocument().remove(start - 1, end - start);
    }
    catch(BadLocationException ble)
    {
        System.out.println(ble);
    }
}
```

Seems to work for other objects as well since the "after" output it different from the "before" output.

I'll let you verify if the text pane updates as expected.

I took the code from [Limit Lines in Document](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/15/limit-lines-in-document/)

Edit:

The above code doesn't work when trying to remove the first line because the  start offset will be negative.

Below is the updated version that also handles removal of the first line:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Test();
    }

    private static final String ELEM = AbstractDocument.ElementNameAttribute;
    private static final String ICON = StyleConstants.IconElementName;
    private static final String COMP = StyleConstants.ComponentElementName;
    private JTextPane outputArea;

    Test() {
        try {
            //init pane
            outputArea = new JTextPane();

            JButton button = new JButton("Remove Last Line");
            button.addActionListener((e) -> removeLastLine());

            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.add( new JScrollPane(outputArea) );
            frame.add( button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(300, 300);
            frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
            frame.setVisible( true );

            println("first line");

            //insert component
            JTextField c = new JTextField(20);
            Style cs = outputArea.getStyledDocument().addStyle("name", null);
            StyleConstants.setComponent(cs, c);
            outputArea.getStyledDocument().insertString(outputArea.getStyledDocument().getLength(), "string", cs);

            //new line
            println("");

            //add string
            println("this is a string added to the pane");

            //add image
            outputArea.insertIcon(new ImageIcon("about16.gif"));

            //new line
            println("\nsecond last line");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void removeLastLine()
    {
        //  We use start minus 1 to make sure we remove the newline
        //  character of the previous line

        Element root = outputArea.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement();
        Element line = root.getElement(root.getElementCount() - 1);
        int start = line.getStartOffset();
        int end = line.getEndOffset();

        try
        {
            int offset = start - 1;
            int length = end - start;

            //  removing the first line

            if (offset < 0)
            {
                offset = 0;
                length -= 1;
            }

            outputArea.getDocument().remove(offset, length);
        }
        catch(BadLocationException ble)
        {
            System.out.println(ble);
        }
    }

    public void println(String Usage) {
        try {
            StyledDocument document = (StyledDocument) outputArea.getDocument();
            document.insertString(document.getLength(), Usage + "\n", null);
            outputArea.setCaretPosition(outputArea.getDocument().getLength());
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works the first time but only for text. It did not work for a JTextField that I added to the JTextPane.

Comment: *This works the first time but only for text* - I tested it by invoking "removeLastLine()` twice and it worked fine.  This implies it did work for the Icon, which implies the code is on the right track. *It did not work for a JTextField* - how did you test this? What error did you get? In your current example the text field is the first object added to the text pane. Did you try the text field as the last object added?  Did you debug the code to see what values are causing the problem?  Still waiting for a better MRE.